# Why do all heavier gases in the atmosphere not settle down to the surface?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, atmospheric-science, density, air, gas

Some pollutants heavier than air that are released into the atmosphere include $\text{CO}_2,\text{SO}_2,\text{SO}_3,\text{NO}_2$ etc. Since these gases are heavier than air, **Why do they not settle down closer to the surface?** By that, I mean why is the concentration of these gases not maximum at sea level?

[This](https://www.atmos-chem-phys.net/11/2455/2011/acp-11-2455-2011.pdf) article has been used as a reference: it is evident that the $\text{CO}_2$ concentration around the 200 HPa band is more than the 800 HPa band in the month of July. Note that this article also does not provide clarity on surface $\text{CO}_2$ levels, it gives data for the 5 km-25 km altitude range.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/247637/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/278154/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34733/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\ CO_2$ is heavier than oxygen and nitrogen still it does not form the lower layer of atmosphere](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/278154/)

Answer (score 2):

The lower portion of the atmosphere (where weather occurs) experiences a lot of vertical mixing. For example, a cumulus cloud that develops into a thunderhead will transport air from near ground-level to heights of 40,000 feet or more. This tends to keep the atmosphere fairly well-mixed.